# The query contains the XXXXXName parameter, which is not declared. SSRS2008/MDX query

Tags: reporting-services, mdx, ssrs-2008, cube

Parser: The query contains the XXXXXName parameter, which is not declared. (msmgdsrv)

I have no idea why I keep getting this error. It occurs when I change the MDX in the query designer and trying OKing out of the query designer.

The strange thing is that the parameter DOES exist, I can see it in the parameters section of the dataset dialog. I am creating it before I do anything else with the query.

Answer (score 8):

Although the seemingly intuitive thing to do is add the Parameter in the Dataset Properties window, this actually does not declare the parameter for the query for some odd reason.

To add the parameter, click the Parameters toolbar button in the Query Designer window. From there you can add your parameter names and default values.

[image]

Once you've done this, the global parameter list will contain that parameter and allow you to use expressions etc..

Comment: I've declared the parameter in the Dataset Properties window, but I still having the same issue.

Comment: This fixed it for me and not only that, after I managed to refresh the fields I noted a field name was changed which solved _another_ issue I was having. This should be the answer.

Comment: But BEWARE: when you open the Query Designer, the MDX code inside is yet another version of code that may not match your original code, and it _overwrite_ your existing code. So before you press OK on the Query Designer, double check the code inside it

Comment: Query Designer is literally a bug.  Do not use.

Comment: Back to the future,  change to the underlying dax query in Query Designer but because the model has changed effecting parameters one can get this error.  The error can be confusing when pointing to the first parameter in the paginated report which is not the parameter in error.  Note the report on the service still runs despite the model changes and changes via Paginated Report Builder dataset properties may also not be effected and runs fine.

Comment: https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Service/Paginated-Report-Builder-bug-showing-unrelated-parameter-error/td-p/2500563#M169565

Answer (score 0):

Is the parameter defined at the report level? That might be what's missing.

Comment: I am trying to connect a report parameter to a query parameter for my DAX query. Any idea how to do that?